How to update visual of Geometrical Path on Canvas C# WPF?
I want to make an interactive plotting of function graphs for given points. For drawing I use Canvas and Path, for manipulations over points I use DataGrid and ObservableCollection. The problem is that when I change the points, the Canvas does not repaint.
UI:
<Window x:Class="WpfAppCharts.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppCharts"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfAppCharts.ViewModels"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfAppCharts.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="WPFCharts" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <converters:DataToPathConverter x:Key="DataToPathConverter"/>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid" Grid.Column="0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid x:Name="DatasDataGrid" Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datas}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"
                  SelectedIndex="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Type,
                                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                              Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lines"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Spline"/>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid x:Name="RecordsDataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DatasDataGrid,
                                        Path=SelectedItem.Records,
                                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=X,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Y,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datas}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="ChartCanvas"
                        Background="Aquamarine"
                        ClipToBounds="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Path Data="{Binding Mode=OneWay,
                                     Converter={StaticResource DataToPathConverter}}"
                      Stroke="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>

Data class:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfAppCharts.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        enum Types { LINES, SPLINE }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
        public Data()
        {
            this.Name = "No name";
            this.Type = (int)Types.SPLINE;
            this.Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        }
    }
}

Record class:
namespace WpfAppCharts.Models
{
    public class Record
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public Record(double X, double Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }
}

ViewModel:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfAppCharts.Models;

namespace WpfAppCharts.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Data> Datas { get; set; }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

            Datas.Add(new Data());
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(0,     0));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(20,    0));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(45,  -47));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(53,  335));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(57,   26));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(62,  387));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(74,  104));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(89,    0));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(95,  100));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(100,   0));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(115, 100));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(120, 200));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(130, 300));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(135, 300));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(140, 200));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(145,  50));
            Datas[0].Records.Add(new Record(150,  50));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

Converter:
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using WpfAppCharts.Models;

namespace WpfAppCharts.Converters
{
    class DataToPathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        enum Types { LINES, SPLINE }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Data data = (Data)value;
            string result = String.Format("M {0},{1}", data.Records[0].X, data.Records[0].Y);
            switch ((int)data.Type)
            {
                case (int)Types.SPLINE:
                case (int)Types.LINES:
                    for (int i = 1; i < data.Records.Count; i++)
                        result += String.Format("L {0},{1}", data.Records[i].X,
                                                             data.Records[i].Y);
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}


The only change notification that can happen with ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datas} and Data="{Binding .} in the ItemTemplate occurs when the Datas collection changes. There is no mechanism that would notify about of a change of the Records property. Even if you write <Path Data={Binding Records, ...}"/> with an appropriate Binding Converter, that Binding would not get notified when elements are added to or removed from the Records collection.

You would have to change the Records property so that its setter raises the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and you would have to assign a new complete collection when Record elements are added.

Besides that, it seems pointless to return a string from the Binding Converter. Better return a PathGeometry.

It is also unclear why you declare enum Types { LINES, SPLINE } twice, instead of declaring Data.Types public. You could avoid casting to int in the switch. Besides that you don't make any sensible use of data.Type.

Maybe there are some tips on how to better organize the project architecture?

I did it like this and now when I run it I get an exception on the line Records = value

public ObservableCollection Records { get => Records; set {
Records = value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Records));
} }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

You could use (tiny) Ellipses and / or colored Rectangles and bind their Canvas.Left and Top to your "Records" in your OC instead of using "path data". At least you'll have some solid object references.
